# Electric static new problem

Tags: electrical

Bought this house last year. Winter, no static. Two,
 weeks ago, in summer, touching kitchen light switches, doorknobs, now kitchen faucet gives me a static shock. Never happened before, now it's consistent. Electrician came out said light switches. It grounded, put little dangling wire inside box behind 2-3 switches. Still happening. Any BTW maybe not relevant but just before this started my Hvac system stopped working, AC guy checked breaker and the wire was loose. Tightened it up, AC worked fine again. Electrician put in a new breaker after that, just to be safe. Coincidence or related? Thanks!

Comment: What's the relative humidity inside the home?

Comment: When you say you get a "static shock" when touching things, do you mean that you get a single momentary spark, or you get a continuous tingling feeling?

Answer (score 3):

Related.  Or at least, you shouldn't take the chance that it's not.

Turn the main breaker off to the entire house and see if it still happens.  That will be the final word on the subject of whether it is electrical related or not.  I suspect it is.

Other than that, don't test it.  Don't tease the dragon.  What feels like a minor pinprick when the rest of you is well insulated from anything metal, can become lethal current flow if you get between something hot and something grounded.

I would not be looking at breakers, I'd be looking at the grounds and neutrals.

A possible cause is the A/C guy misusing a ground as a neutral.  This can easily combine with another type of failure to put dangerous voltage on every ground in the house, i.e. Every switch cover plate, all metal conduit, dryer or stove chassis, even the circuit breaker panel itself.  The "other type of failure" might be the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

If touching doorknobs produces a shock, that doesn't sound like a ground fault, since doorknobs are never grounded.

I think the hint might be that its started happening since the AC was fixed. With the AC working, the relative humidity in the house would have been reduced, perhaps to the point that static generation and consequent shocks are produced.

That's really efficient AC! But strange that there's no shocks in winter when the RH is normally really low. Unless you live in an area where the winter temp doesn't drop below freezing. I'm told such places exist ;)