# What's causing constant static shock in new house?

Tags: electrical

I live in South Florida (where it's humid) and my new construction house is constantly zapping us when we touch metal like the front door handle. The entire house is tile, and the air isn't very dry so I really don't know what can be causing the static shock all the time. My neighbor who has an identical house does not have this issue.

Any ideas on what can be causing this? What kind of contractor should I even reach out to investigate the issue?

Comment: Constant as in everything you touch? Or just like you get up off the couch, touch the fridge and zap, then no more zaps?

Comment: Related https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/98384/why-is-voltage-detected-in-my-ceramic-tile-floor.     Is your house a slab floor?

Comment: With static electricity, it's one momentary pow. That discharges you, and you won't get zapped again unless you move a fair bit to build up another static charge. If you get zapped, and then touch it again without really moving, does it zap you again?

Comment: Be sure to read this https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/92559/46271.

Comment: Has something changed in your laundry or clothing habits? Some fabrics can be remarkably prone to producing static charges when they're not routinely treated with anti-static dryer sheets, spray, etc. I have no idea whether characteristics of the water feeding the clothes washing machine (hardness or ion concentration?) might affect the static production differently than the water at your last house did.